# Java using scanner for user input to set size of array

Tags: java, arrays

I want to allow for the user to be able to choose the size of the int array in my program

Right now I have the following code:

```
public class SortTests {
    private static int size;
    private static int [] myArray = new int [size]; 

    public static void setArraySize() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number to specify the size of the array: ");
        size = scan.nextInt();
        
    }
    
    public static void fillArray() {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
            myArray[i] = randNum.nextInt(100);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure why but when I go to test and print my Array.toString it simply prints '''[]''' (obviously it is not doing what it should be doing and populating the int array).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can tidy my code smell up and make it so this actually works?

Comment: because the array is declared with size 0. Just because you update the size variable, doesn't mean array is also going to get redeclared.

Comment: You allocate an array of size 0 and then set the size variable later. Java isn't going to retroactively go back and resize the array unless you tell it to. Code happens in the order you tell it to run in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created the array already, and your setArraySize changes the size variable only.

```
public class SortTests {
    private static int size; <-- setArraySize affects this.
    private static int [] myArray = new int [size];  <-- setArraySize does not affect this.  Size was defaulted to 0, so myArray will always be a 0-sized array.
```

Change to something similar to this:

```
public class SortTests {
    private static int [] myArray = new int [size]; 

    public static void setArraySize() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number to specify the size of the array: ");
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        myArray = Arrays.copyOf(myArray, size);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @John's answer

This is not the correct way to initialize Arrays. You're using the compiler-provided default value for for an int (which is 0) to initialize the length of `myArray`. The initialization of `myArray` occurs on class instantiation. This means that `size` is read once when the class is created, then discarded. Thus, the initial array size from the code you provided will always be the length of the original value of `size`. Since `size` was 0, it is proper for the array to be empty.

If you want to retrieve an array of a specific size, you need to create it dynamically after the user has submitted his input (Per @John's answer)

Additionally, you will definitely want to consider using Java's Collections framework instead of dealing with raw Arrays. Array sizes are managed dynamically.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerToArraySize {

    private static Integer size;
    private static ArrayList<Integer> myArray = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void setArraySize() {
        Scanner  scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a whole number to specify the size of the array: ");
        size = scan.nextInt();
    }

    public static void fillArray() {
        Random randNum = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            myArray.add(randNum.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public static void printArray(){
        for (Integer integer : myArray) {
            System.out.println(integer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Incorrect. 1. he's not using a null reference to initialize the array.  He's using 0, which is the default value for an int type member variable.  2. an array and a list are 2 different things.  without knowing the requirements, you cannot simply change the data structure.

Comment: 1. Yes, It is true that it is not a null reference. I've modified my answer to reflect that. 2. I know that Collections and Arrays are two different things. You kindly provided the correct answer for Raw Array management. This answer is meant to provide unique content that may provide insight into better programming practices. If the OP is not required to stick with Raw Arrays, this answer is more suitable.